# Delphi Runtime Error 105 at 0040423F

Tags: delphi

I currently have a question for Delphi.Every time when i want to run  the program it shows me this problem:Runtime error 105 at 0040423F. Here is the picture of it and the program behind it:

[image: ERROR PICTURE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your source code to add the line shown below:

```
program sss;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
   [etc]
  readln()  // <- the program will pause here until you press the Return key
end.
```

The error you were getting was to tell you your program was being denied access to the standard output stream, which is where the output from a writeln() statement is written, because it isn't open for output.

Comment: Oh thanks, But i want to ask you one thing how to use readkey as c#. Cause my program starts quickly and closes !

Comment: Ok. Tell me why the program its quckly closed every time when i start it ?

Comment: Once you've got it to run by the change I said, just add "readln()" to the end and the console window will stay open until you press the Return key.

Comment: Why would you expect execution not to end once it reached the end of the program?

Answer (score 0):

105 Error is you are doing a "Console Output" in a GUI App!

Also note: Alexandria v11.2 has the same stupid bug!
[image]

FASTMM4.PAS is doing a Writeln() - So you should not feel bad, when the developers of the compiler do the same Delphi 101 Error!!

*To Embaradero: DUMBASSES!*